# Realm object field using default value based on another field

Tags: typescript, realm, realm-js

When using an arrow function as default value in the Realm schema definition, is there a way to access a value defined in another field from this function ?

Because I have 2 IDs fields in my objets and they must be the same at creation (and then after updates only one is changing).

So I would like to achieve something like :

```
rowId: { type: 'uuid', default: () => new BSON.UUID() }
branchId: { type: 'uuid', default: () => this.rowId }, // error because _this_ is not the realm object...`
```

Comment: Are you asking if a two properties in a Realm object can be initialized with the same value, a UUID? If so, that leads to the question; why have two properties that will only contain the same static value? What's the use case?

Comment: Yes I am asking for that, since UUID is random, when I generate one and assign it as default value for a field, I need a way to access it in order to assign it to the other field.
 
About the reason, I explained why in the question : those 2 IDs are identical only at creation time. When the row is updated later, one of the ID will be updated, not the other (there's a kind of audit trail feature behind).

Comment: Is using an object constructor an option? I don't believe you can use *this* on an uninstantiated object so you have to use the full reference. So if your object `myObject` had a property `someVar : 1` and then another var would be `anotherVar: myObject.someVar`. You may also be able to use a function as the constructor for the object.

Comment: I didn't find how to implement constructor in my realm classes as they are supposed to call super with an argument that I can't provide :(

Comment: A quick search here on SO reveals quite a number of questions of how to work with constructors in realm. Take a look at [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brealm%5Dconstructor)